# How do i active ADX Com Add-in under Extensibility of VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin

I have installed VS 2010 in order to office programing (an extension for outlook )

In sample i find ADX Com Add-in under Extensibility New Project->other project types->Extensibility->ADX Com Add-in.but   For me it is not available.

What should i do to enable this?
should i install another package or some thing like this to have this item in my new project menu .

does it refer to my vs version or the way that i have instaled it or something else .i have searched all the net  but unfortunately i have found nothing  useful.

what should i do to have this par tain my VS2010?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

ADX Com Add-in is not a Standard Microsoft modele project. You need to go on the editor web site, download and PAY around 250$ to use this modele.